# Images show in Chrome and Firefox but not in Safari

Tags: html, image, google-chrome, safari, href

In my website, i have five links in the footer.
Which one, redirect to the social media page of the company. Those links have images.
In Chrome, it's showed right, but in Safari isn't. I have the screenshots...

Chrome
[image: http://imageshack.com/a/img537/3628/Hp0H7P.png]

Safari
[image: http://imageshack.com/a/img540/6461/fUZ3kC.png]

```
 <div>
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/escolaprofissional.tondela" target="_blank"><img src="images/facebook.png"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <a href="https://instagram.com/eptondela/" target="_blank"><img src="images/instagram.png"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <a href="http://eptondela.tumblr.com" target="_blank"><img src="images/tumblr.png"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <a href="https://twitter.com/eptondela" target="_blank"><img src="images/twitter.png"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <a href="https://www.youtube.com/user/eptondela" target="_blank"><img src="images/youtube.png"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
 </div>
```

Chrome - all work!
Safari - don't show images and the links neither, like if don't exist

Thanks,

Comment: What does inspecting the page reveal? Are the elements there?

Comment: Yes, it shows the div, if it's what you asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is simple: You have got AdBlock installed. It also blocks Social Media icons.